# Are there any aftermarket temperature or leak sensors?

Tags: leak, temperature

It seems to me the biggest threat to a car is when it leaks or overheats and people don't stop driving.

I always forgot to check the temperature because the symbol is so small and I am concentrating on the road.

Are there any aftermarket temperature or leak sensors that will alert you in case of these that are worth buying?